# use object destructuring react issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Hell,
Am new to react js and having an issue when committing my code to GitHub. When I commit am getting the following error, please can anyone help me out. Below is the code and error message.

Having an issue with line 163 to 192 with use object destructuring.

```
import React from 'react';

const scaleNames = {
    sd: 'Sodium (mg)',
    sl: 'Salt (g)'
};

interface SSConverterProps {
    onRecommendedChange?: any;
    recommended?: any;
    scale?: any;
}

interface SSConverterStates {
    recommended: any;
    scale: any;
    RecommendedInput?: any;
}


function toSodium(salt) {
    return (salt * 1000) / 2.5;
}

function toSalt(sodium) {
    return (sodium * 2.5) / 1000;
}

function tryConvert(recommended, convert) {
    const input = parseFloat(recommended);
    if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
        return '';
    }
    const output = convert(input);
    const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
    return rounded.toString();
}

function RecommendedVerdict(props: { sodium: number }) {
    if (props.sodium < 500) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    0 - 1.25 grams of salt (this is less than a quarter of your
                    recommended daily intake)
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Australian adults are recommended to consume less than 5g
                    (less than 1 teaspoon) of salt a day.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information call our Heart Foundation Helpline on
                    13 11 12.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if (props.sodium >= 500 && props.sodium < 1000) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    1.25 - 2.5 grams of salt (this is approaching half of your
                    recommended daily intake)
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Australian adults are recommended to consume less than 5g
                    (less than 1 teaspoon) of salt a day.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information call our Heart Foundation Helpline on
                    13 11 12.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if (props.sodium >= 1000 && props.sodium < 1500) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    2.5 - 3.75 grams of salt (this is over half of your
                    recommended daily intake)
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Australian adults are recommended to consume less than 5g
                    (less than 1 teaspoon) of salt a day.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information call our Heart Foundation Helpline on
                    13 11 12.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if (props.sodium >= 1500 && props.sodium < 2000) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    3.75 - 5 grams of salt (this is approaching your recommended
                    daily intake)
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Australian adults are recommended to consume less than 5g
                    (less than 1 teaspoon) of salt a day.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information call our Heart Foundation Helpline on
                    13 11 12.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if (props.sodium === 2000) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    5 grams of salt (this is more than your recommended daily
                    intake)
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Australian adults are recommended to consume less than 5g
                    (less than 1 teaspoon) of salt a day.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information call our Heart Foundation Helpline on
                    13 11 12.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if (props.sodium > 2000) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    5 grams of salt or more (this is more than your recommended
                    daily intake)
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Australian adults are recommended to consume less than 5g
                    (less than 1 teaspoon) of salt a day.
                </p>
                <p>
                    For more information call our Heart Foundation Helpline on
                    13 11 12.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return <p> </p>;
}


class RecommendedInput extends React.Component<SSConverterProps, SSConverterStates> {
    public constructor(props: Readonly<SSConverterProps>) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    public handleChange(e) {
        this.props.onRecommendedChange(e.target.value);
    }

    public render() {
        const recommended = this.props.recommended;
        const scale = this.props.scale;
        return (
            <div className="__field">
                <label>{scaleNames[scale]}</label>
                <input value={recommended} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SSConverter extends React.Component<SSConverterProps, SSConverterStates> {
    public constructor(props: Readonly<SSConverterProps>) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSodiumChange = this.handleSodiumChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSaltChange = this.handleSaltChange.bind(this);
        this.state = { recommended: '', scale: 'sd' };
    }

    public handleSodiumChange(recommended) {
        this.setState({ scale: 'sd', recommended });
    }

    public handleSaltChange(recommended) {
        this.setState({ scale: 'sl', recommended });
    }

    public render() {
        const scale = this.state.scale;
        const recommended = this.state.recommended;
        const sodium =
            scale === 'sl' ? tryConvert(recommended, toSodium) : recommended;
        const salt =
            scale === 'sd' ? tryConvert(recommended, toSalt) : recommended;

        return (
            <div>
                <h2
                    className="f_avalon_mid_large"
                    id="convert_sodium_to_salt_or_vice_versa_21"
                >
                    Convert Sodium to Salt or vice versa.
                </h2>
                <div className="inputField">
                    <RecommendedInput
                        scale="sd"
                        recommended={sodium}
                        onRecommendedChange={this.handleSodiumChange}
                    />
                    <RecommendedInput
                        scale="sl"
                        recommended={salt}
                        onRecommendedChange={this.handleSaltChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <RecommendedVerdict sodium={parseFloat(sodium)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SSConverter;
```

So when I tried to push it to the repo, I am getting errors on line 163 to 192 which is saying as use object destructuring, I did do a research on it and add the const but that also did not work. I'm confused where I have gone wrong.

Comment: We can't see line numbers and I doubt we need everything here. Either please separate the problem lines for us and/or make sure this is a [mre]. Keyword: Minimal

Comment: sorry about that below is the lines where i have issue with `public render() {
        const recommended = this.props.recommended;
        const scale = this.props.scale;`

Comment: What/where is the error message? Are you sure this is an error or is it rather an eslint warning about destructuring properties from state and props? I didn't see anywhere in your snippet where you are using object destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a lint error, try changing these lines:

```
const scale = this.state.scale;
const recommended = this.state.recommended;
```

```
const scale = this.props.scale;
const recommended = this.props.recommended;
```

to use object destructuring;

```
const { scale, recommended } = this.state;
```

```
const { scale, recommended } = this.props;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment